# Are components supposed to be released from memory when you change routes?

Tags: typescript, memory-management, garbage-collection, angular7

I have built an angular application and there seems to be a very large memory leak occurring because the component objects are not getting released from memory.

In the application there is a home component which is the component you are navigated to after logging in. From the home component the user has the option to navigate to a view form component which create a large allocation of memory.

The main problem i am having is that every time i navigate away from the view form component back to the home component the view form component is never released from memory. The home component doesn't seem to be released either, if i navigate back and forth between home component and view form component 4 times then i would see 4 of each component in my heap snapshot (taken with chrome dev tools).

The view form component has many other components nested within it, and it also makes use of a very large very deeply nested angular FormGroup.

I am using the global shim for window in my applications pollyfills.js.

My components make use of many Observables and BehaviorSubjects (rxjs 6.3.3), i am using the method of pushing all my subscriptions onto an array and unsubscribing onDestroy.

I made and scratch angular project and i mimicked the routing done in the real application and i saw the the components were removed from the heap snapshot as expected.

Comment: Been a long time, but have you found the answer to your case? I seem to be facing a similar issue